# Is it possible to use fewer paths to achieve the same affect?

Tags: svg

Considering [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5v7sdy8/):

[image: SVG Speech bubble]

I have the same path 5 times so that I can perform some filters on it:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="649" height="173" viewBox="0 0 649 173">

  <!-- paths -->
  <path class="cls-3" d="M69,35H595a20,20,0,0,1,20,20V80a20,20,0,0,1-20,20H69A20,20,0,0,1,49,80V55A20,20,0,0,1,69,35Zm477,65s-4.027,26.227,44,44c0.254,0.094-30.858-26.75-14-44C576.221,99.774,546,100,546,100Z" filter="url(#blur3)" />
  <path class="cls-3" d="M69,35H595a20,20,0,0,1,20,20V80a20,20,0,0,1-20,20H69A20,20,0,0,1,49,80V55A20,20,0,0,1,69,35Zm477,65s-4.027,26.227,44,44c0.254,0.094-30.858-26.75-14-44C576.221,99.774,546,100,546,100Z" filter="url(#blur3)" />
  <path class="cls-2" d="M69,35H595a20,20,0,0,1,20,20V80a20,20,0,0,1-20,20H69A20,20,0,0,1,49,80V55A20,20,0,0,1,69,35Zm477,65s-4.027,26.227,44,44c0.254,0.094-30.858-26.75-14-44C576.221,99.774,546,100,546,100Z" filter="url(#blur2)" />
  <path class="cls-2" d="M69,35H595a20,20,0,0,1,20,20V80a20,20,0,0,1-20,20H69A20,20,0,0,1,49,80V55A20,20,0,0,1,69,35Zm477,65s-4.027,26.227,44,44c0.254,0.094-30.858-26.75-14-44C576.221,99.774,546,100,546,100Z" filter="url(#blur2)" />
  <path class="cls-1" d="M69,35H595a20,20,0,0,1,20,20V80a20,20,0,0,1-20,20H69A20,20,0,0,1,49,80V55A20,20,0,0,1,69,35Zm477,65s-4.027,26.227,44,44c0.254,0.094-30.858-26.75-14-44C576.221,99.774,546,100,546,100Z" filter="url(#blur1)" />

  <!-- filters -->
  <filter id="blur1">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" />
  </filter>
  <filter id="blur2">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1" />
  </filter>
  <filter id="blur3">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="3" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

I would rather have 1 path with a complex filter. Judging by the docs on MDN, I should be able to accomplish this, but it's not clear to me how.

---

#### Extra info

The MDN documentation provides the following example:

```
<svg width="120" height="120"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <filter id="dropShadow">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" />
    <feOffset dx="2" dy="4" />
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode />
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
    </feMerge>
  </filter>

  <circle cx="60"  cy="60" r="50" fill="green"
          filter="url(#dropShadow)" />
</svg>
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

As you can see this accomplished the multiple layers without multiple paths.

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve? a blur with a stdDeviation of 0 does nothing for instance.

Comment: Good point. I'll remove/update the question. I'm going for the rest

Answer (score 1):

This should be absolutely possible with one or two paths. To get the code for the filter I can really recommend you to use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org). I offers a filter editor, which is specially designed to create complex filters. The Interface for of the filter editor is designed in the way SVG filters work, so you can in some sort of way, plug the output of one into the input of another filter.

A simple dropshadow filter could look like this in the editor pane:
[image: example]

So this is a very good way to model and to understand svg filters.

I hope I could help.

**Update**

Here the result:

[image]

A full and complete explanation of such filters and the way how to assemble those, goes far beyond the scope of an answer here, but a good book, which I found very useful for that might be [that](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002237.do).

**UPDATE #2**

The best of that approach is: After saving within inkscape, you can open the created file and view the source of the resulting filter, in best case, copy and paste is your friend. ;)

Comment: While I was excited to try this, my SVG is broken when I open in Inkscape. Everything is black instead of following my colours

Comment: Well, there are a number of thing that can go wrong, I often had the case where the `viewBox` Attribute of the SVG was wrong/missing… Try to use the »outline view« (view > outline), to see if you can find the paths (pan and zoom). If so, mark them and got to File > Doc. Preferences and select, resize to selection. If your filters are broken, black might be the only thing to see. Might be better to recreate the whole filter.

Comment: All in all, inkscape is great for learning those effects, but it handles coordinates in its way, even if there are much more other ways to define it in svg.

Comment: This tool isn't totally intuitive (I don't blame them, neither is SVG's filter system). I'm gonna see if I can get a similar effect on a simple shape and then if it works you got yourself an answer marked correct

Comment: I agree! But it is way better than to do everything in code, I think...

Comment: I ended up doing it with code lol. These tools were more confusing than helpful :(

Answer (score 0):

## [Got it.](http://jsfiddle.net/d5v7sdy8/2/)

---

#### "Okay, but *how*?"

**Firstly**, `#blur1` was useless, as @robert-longson pointed out:

```
<filter id="blur1"><filter id="blur1">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" />
</filter>
```

A gaussian blur of 0 is the same image. Duh!

**Next,** I just looked at what I was trying to do when I was repeating the paths and found relevant SVG filters:

- I wanted a new color - `feFlood`
- I wanted it to be blurred - `feGaussianBlur`
- I wanted it to be expanded a bit - `feMorphology`

**Finally,** after a bit of playing around, I got it working:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="649" height="173" viewBox="0 0 649 173">
  <def>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #D4DEF8;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #6ACDFD;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        fill: #0030DB;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
    </style>
  </def>

  <path class="cls-1" d="M69,35H595a20,20,0,0,1,20,20V80a20,20,0,0,1-20,20H69A20,20,0,0,1,49,80V55A20,20,0,0,1,69,35Zm477,65s-4.027,26.227,44,44c0.254,0.094-30.858-26.75-14-44C576.221,99.774,546,100,546,100Z" filter="url(#glow)" />

  <filter id="glow">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2.5" result="coloredBlur"/>

    <!-- First glow -->
    <feFlood result="flood1" flood-color="#6ACDFD" floodOpacity="1"></feFlood>
    <feComposite in="flood1" result="mask1" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
    <feMorphology in="mask1" result="dilated1" operator="dilate" radius="1"></feMorphology>
    <feGaussianBlur in="dilated1" result="blurred1" stdDeviation="2"></feGaussianBlur>

    <!-- Second glow -->
    <feFlood result="flood2" flood-color="#0030DB" floodOpacity="1"></feFlood>
    <feComposite in="flood2" result="mask2" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
    <feMorphology in="mask2" result="dilated2" operator="dilate" radius="5"></feMorphology>
    <feGaussianBlur in="dilated2" result="blurred2" stdDeviation="3"></feGaussianBlur>

    <!-- Pop em in -->
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="blurred2"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="blurred1"></feMergeNode>

        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
  </filter>

</svg>
```

[image]

---

#### "Woah, nice."

Thanks. Some things to keep in mind:

- Keep track of your `in` and `result` values - these are how you "pipe" filters to/from one another. Specifically, `in` lets you dictate where the filter should be applied to, and `result` is a name you assign to the result of the filter.
- The order of these filters is (obviously) very important
- Use the `feMerge` and `feMergeNode` to "merge" the filters into the final render